# Mockito mock HttpServletRequest for interceptor

Tags: java, mockito, spring-test

I have to check that some interceptor logic is invoked.
Interceptor gets user principal via request.getUserPrincipal. So I mocked HttpServletRequest to provide some custom logic.
However request.getUserPrincipal is always null, because instead of my mocked servletRequest, mockMvc generated data is applied

```
@WebMvcTest(value = MyApi.class)
public class UserDetailsInterceptorTest {
    private static final String USER = "User";
    private static final String ROLE = "Manager";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    private final String rootUrl = "/v1/my/info";
    
    @Test
    void interceptPositive() throws Exception {
        Principal principal = () -> USER;
        KeycloakAccount account = new SimpleKeycloakAccount(principal, Collections.singleton(ROLE), null);
        when(request.getUserPrincipal()).thenReturn(new KeycloakAuthenticationToken(account,false));
        mockMvc.perform(get(rootUrl)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        //check interceptors        
    }
}

@Component
public class UserDetailsInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        AccessToken token = null;
        String tokenString  = null;
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal(); //null despite beeing mocked
        //other code    
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of mocking HttpServletRequest or providing principal with Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that mockMvc actually allows to pass a principal directly

```
mockMvc.perform(get(rootUrl)
        .principal(principal) //this way
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

No mocking HttpServletRequest needed